# Why I cannot plot edges of networkx in iplot_mpl() method of plotly

Tags: python, plotly, networkx

I am trying to plot a graph using `networkx` library. Additionally, I want to plot it as an interactive figure by `plotly` in `Jypyter`, so firstly I modified the [demo code](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.2/auto_examples/drawing/plot_directed.html) to draw a static graph using `networkx` (see the top one of the following figure), then I used `iplot_mpl()` method to convert the figure to an interactive figure via `plotly`. However, edges did not show in the graph (see the bottom one).

[image: net]

The code is the following,

```py
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from plotly.offline import (init_notebook_mode,
                            iplot_mpl)


init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

G = nx.generators.directed.random_k_out_graph(10, 3, 0.5)
pos = nx.layout.spring_layout(G)

node_sizes = [3 + 10 * i for i in range(len(G))]
M = G.number_of_edges()
edge_colors = range(2, M + 2)
edge_alphas = [(5 + i) / (M + 4) for i in range(M)]

fig = plt.figure()

nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=node_sizes, node_color='blue')
edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, node_size=node_sizes, arrowstyle='->',
                               arrowsize=10, edge_color=edge_colors,
                               edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues, width=2)
# for the top figure
plt.show()

# for the bottom figure
iplot_mpl(fig)
```

I also tried to use `draw_networkx()` insted of `draw_networkx_nodes()`and `draw_networkx_edges()`. Unfortunately, the edge still did not show. Moreover, I also set the `ax` parameter in `draw_networkx()` method, the result is the same...

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nx.draw_networkx(..., ax=ax)
```

Thanks in advance for your comments!

Comment: I also report this on GitHub community of `plotly` ([link](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1566)), it seems this is an issue about `matplotlib` now.